# Iptables MASQUERADE only selected ports

Tags: linux, networking, port-forwarding, iptables

I did port forwarding following this tutorial:
http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-redirecting-network-traffic-to-a-new-ip-using-iptables/

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1111 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:1111

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

But i want to MASQUERADE just the ports with the forwardings, because in the same server i have a webserver and if i MASQUERADE all the traffic the web server stops working.

Any idea?

SOLUTION: 
`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 2.2.2.2 -p tcp --dport 1111 -j SNAT --to-source 2.2.2.1`

Comment: Just apply the filter to match only outgoing packets to port from port iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING - p tcp --sport 1111 -j MASQUERADE

Comment: tried adding a tighter match rules? For example, only masquerade when traffic leaves specific interface: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE or even comes from specific network: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.5.0/24 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE and so on

Comment: @Zalmy  it makes sense for me, but it's not working. BTW you have a typo `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --sport 1111 -j MASQUERADE` (a space between - p) This was not the error, because i set up like this `2    MASQUERADE  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:40002` and it doesn't work, any idea??  Thanks

Comment: ... er, hang on, you're trying to source NAT everything you've already DNAT'd?  Why?  The DNAT should already take care of the reply traffic, that part of iptables connection tracks, it has to or no NAT works.  If the DNAT is a standard port forward to an internal subnet, and you just need to MASQ that internal subnet, that I would understand and just filter for that.  The blanket MASQ you have up there with no criteria would run MASQ in both directions, and it's no wonder everything screws up.

Comment: OK, I've read the tutorial, and I've actually not seen NAT used this way.  I suppose it could be, but it's not a redirection or a port forward in so much as it's using the box as a middleman translator, and it's not a great solution because it convinces all clients that it runs the service and the server that it's the only client.  Zalmy has the right idea but the rule should be matching the new dport or destination IP, which you've already set in the DNAT.  so try -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 2.2.2.2 -p tcp --dport 1111 -j MASQUERADE.  Will write up clearer as an answer if I understand correctly.

Comment: SOLUTION:  `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 2.2.2.2 -p tcp --dport 1111 -j SNAT --to-source 2.2.2.1`

Comment: Why you solution does not have `--sport`?

Answer (score 1):

if you **really** want to do a `MASQUERADE` then the proper way to do this is like this:

```bsh
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1111 -j DNAT --to-destination 2.2.2.2:1111
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 2.2.2.2 -p tcp --dport 1111 -j MASQUERADE
```

this way `MASQUERADE` will be applied only to DNAT-ed packets.

Note however that `MASQUERADE` is intended mostly for dynamic IP cases (such as dial-up) and in case of a static IP `SNAT` should rather be used just the way you proposed. From `iptables` man page:

> It should  only  be
>   used  with  dynamically assigned IP (dialup) connections: if you have a static IP address,
>   you should use the SNAT target.  Masquerading is equivalent to specifying a mapping to the
>   IP  address of the interface the packet is going out, but also has the effect that 
>   connections are forgotten when the interface goes down.  This is the correct behavior  when  the
>   next dialup is unlikely to have the same interface address (and hence any established connections are lost anyway).

there is 1 caveat though for both `MASQUERADE` and `SNAT`: it won't work if 2.2.2.2 is a VIP on the same machine.